# Row-wise replace operation in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

In the given data frame, I am trying to perform a row-wise replace operation where 1 should be replaced by the value in Values.

**Input:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,1,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7], 
                   'A': [0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,np.nan,0],
                   'B': [0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
                   'C': [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1],
                   'Values': [10, 2, 3,4,9,3,4,5,2,3]})
```

**Expected Output:**

```
   ID   A   B   C   Values
0   1   0.0 0   10  10
1   1   2.0 0   0   2
2   1   0.0 0   3   3
3   2   4.0 0   0   4
4   3   0.0 9   0   9
5   3   0.0 3   0   3
6   4   4.0 0   0   4
7   5   0.0 0   0   5
8   6   NaN 0   2   2
9   7   0.0 0   3   3
```

**Note: The data is very large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df.where`

```
 df[['A','B','C']]=df[['A','B','C']].where(df[['A','B','C']].ne(1),df['Values'], axis=0)



ID    A  B   C  Values
0   1  0.0  0  10      10
1   1  2.0  0   0       2
2   1  0.0  0   3       3
3   2  4.0  0   0       4
4   3  0.0  9   0       9
5   3  0.0  3   0       3
6   4  4.0  0   0       4
7   5  0.0  0   0       5
8   6  NaN  0   2       2
9   7  0.0  0   3       3
```

Or

```
df[['A','B','C']]=df[['A','B','C']].mask(df[['A','B','C']].eq(1),df['Values'], axis=0)
```

Comment: My data is really large and it is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

> My data is really large and it is very slow.

If we exploit the nature of your dataset (A, B, C columns have `1s` or `0s` or `Nans`), you simply have to multiple `df['values']` with each column independently. This should be super fast as it is vectorized.

```
df['A'] = df['A']*df['Values']
df['B'] = df['B']*df['Values']
df['C'] = df['C']*df['Values']

print(df)
```

```
   ID    A  B   C  Values
0   1  0.0  0  10      10
1   1  2.0  0   0       2
2   1  0.0  0   3       3
3   2  4.0  0   0       4
4   3  0.0  9   0       9
5   3  0.0  3   0       3
6   4  4.0  0   0       4
7   5  0.0  0   0       5
8   6  NaN  0   2       2
9   7  0.0  0   3       3
```

---

If you want to explicitly check the condition where values of A, B, C are 1 (maybe because those columns could have values other than Nans or 0s), then you can use this -

```
df[['A','B','C']] = (df[['A','B','C']] == 1)*df[['Values']].values
```

This will replace the columns A, B, C in the original data but, also replaces Nans with 0.